# Display database content in css circle - nonresponsive

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create non-responsive progress circles to display database content (if that makes sense?).

For example, I want it to look like

[image]

I want it to display content from the database, for example, `@test.correct_answers_count` or `@test.percentage`

Comment: You could use a jquery plugin called [Easy Pie](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/). If you're using javascript to get data back from server using for each key value pair insert the value onto the looped element on the dom. Look into https://angularjs.org/ makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, it does work quite easily!

Answer (score 1):

SVG's are a good way to handle circular elements. Its hard to use CSS to get borders to be rounded, which have a beginning and end you can accurately control.

Here is an SVG path which is nearly a circle, but the top point (at 12 o'clock) isn't joined up:

```
<svg class='version-1' x="0px" y="0px"
     width="142.924px" height="142.924px" viewBox="0 0 142.924 142.924">
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M71.462,13.129
    c32.217,0,58.334,26.116,58.334,58.333s-26.117,58.334-58.334,58.334s-58.333-26.117-58.333-58.334S39.245,13.129,71.462,13.129"/>
</svg>
```

So, if you want to use CSS now what we can do is **dash** the line. We are going to create a dash starting from the beginning, with a length like so:

```
svg path{
  stroke-dasharray: 364px 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  stroke: red;
}
```

This gives it a path the whole way around. Why 364px? Because pi x diameter (118px) is the circumference of the circle. The first number (364) is the dash length, and the second one is the gap – the two together should make 364 or whatever the diameter of your circle.

From here, you can do some pretty straight forward stuff.

```
100% = 364px;
60% = 364 / 100 * 60 = 218.4px;
10% = 364 / 100 * 10 = 36.4px;
```

Lets take a look at how those work out!

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/GgzRXa/

#### Edit

All this said its probably much easier to use a jQuery plugin as mentioned in the comments – there are times to create your own thing and times to just use something someone else has gone to the hard work of creating.

Comment: I see what you mean I think, but how do I use this with the database content? I can't set the css as 364px, because I don't know what percentage the user will have yet?

Comment: You could take the data from the database and then just inline it, for example the SVG path would look like `<path fill="none" stroke-dasharray='<?php echo $percentage_value; ?>' ...`. If the question is "how do I get data out of a database" that may be a much bigger question!

Comment: I think I'll take the advice of your edit and use the Easy Pie Chart jquery plugin as it seems to be relatively easy. Thanks though!